# Migration of email account to addon domain on new Web Host

Tags: dns, email, domain-registration, mx, add-on-domain

I took over the work from another web developer and try to figure out, how he migrated an email account from old Webhost + Domain (domainA, hostA) to a new Webhost + Domain (domainB, hostB).

This is the configuration:

#### domainA

- website: `domainA.example` on hostA
- email account: `info@domainA.example`

#### domainB

- website: `domainB.example` on hostB
- email account: `info@domainA.example` (yes, domainA)

domainA is added as addon domain on hostB. When I send an email to info@domainA.com the email only appears on web server B (I can see it in File Manager) not on web server A.

HostingA is cancelled the next week. (including the domainA). It seems, that I cannot manage the domainA in the admin panel anymore, but I think he did it before the cancellation.

I tried to find out how this "redirecting" of the emails works, by searching some redirecting settings on admin panel + cpanel on hostA but I just can't find it.

So, how did he do that?

I'd be happy for any explanations. I want to unterstand this because I want to renew the registration of domainA and wants to be sure, that the email address info@domainA.com will still work after accomplished cancellation of hostingA next week.

Comment: What are your DNS records for domainA and domainB?  Especially relevant or the `MX` records which are for email.

Comment: further to @StephenOstermiller - check intodns.com

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for your comment! I checked the MX records on domainA but it is pointing to hostA. But I found out, that the previous web developer already transferred domainA to another registrar. I will check the MX records there when I got the log in credential of the new registrar. I think, I will find my answers there. :)

Comment: @Steve thank you so much for this link! That confirmed my guess, that the MX record is set to hostB.

Comment: Considering answering your own question so that future visitors can see the solution

Answer (score 1):

I checked the MX records in the zone editor of where I thought domainA's DNS was hosted and found it was pointing to hostA.

But I discovered that domainA's DNS had been moved to another host.

When I checked the MX records of domainA at intodns.com I discovered that the active DNS is hosted at hostB. So I was originally looking in the wrong place.